# Crond is running twice with CentOS

Tags: centos, cron, centos6

I have the following issue that all of my cronjobs are running twice.

When I do:

```
ps aux | grep cron
```

I see the following:

```
root      1379  0.0  0.1 117296  1224 ?        Ss   Aug26   0:00 crond
root     17177  0.0  0.0 103248   860 pts/0    S+   10:42   0:00 grep cron
```

Two instances. The last one recreates each minute, so you can see time is currently 10:42 am over here. Each minute the instances gets killed and a new one starts with new pid.

Is it here the problem is? How can I solve this?

I am using CentOS 6.

Comment: Where do you see two instances of crond? The output you posted shows only one.

Comment: If you want suppress grep in the output you should do `ps aux | grep cron
| grep -v grep`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's basically a misread of the grep output.  http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6160/174813

Answer (score 1):

when you do `ps aux | grep cron` you are running two commands - `ps aux` and `grep cron`. `ps aux` lists all processes currently running, and `grep cron` matches any lines which contain "cron" in them.

Obviously the crond process matches the word `cron`, but so does the `grep cron` process you just ran. It's matching itself recursively.